# Bootstrap Datetimepicker glyphicon calendar is not open

Tags: jquery-ui, glyphicons, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I will try to use Eonasdan datetimepicker v4 version. I am using bootstrap version v3.2.0. I have added the following js and css files in my jsp page,

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/transition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/collapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

```js
 $(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker'+rowIndx).datetimepicker();
   });
```

```html
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value=""  style="width:160px;height:26px;width:140px;size:12px;font-family:Arial" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span></div></div></div></div>
```

Here, glyphicon calendar is not open. How can I start v4 version eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker as without issue. If I click icon, the calendar also not open. Please help me.

Comment: Please anyone help me. How can I do this?